# Generating Barnsley Fern Fractal in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

The (flawed) code is as followed:

```
function fern()

AI = [0  0 ; 0 0.16];
AII = [ 0.85  0.04 ; -0.04 -0.85 ] ;
AIII = [ 0.2  -0.26 ; 0.23 0.22 ] ;
AIV = [-0.15  0.28 ; 0.26 0.24 ];


BI = [ 0 ; 0];
BII = [ 0 ; 1.6];
BIII = [ 0 ; 1.6];
BIV = [0 ; 0.44];

N = 10000;
I = 50;

H = zeros(N,2);

for n=1 : N

x = rand;
y = rand;
T = [x;y];


for i=1 : I

    p = rand;

    if p < 0.01
        %disp('Scheme 1')
        S1x = AI*T + BI;
        S1y = AI*T + BI;
        x = S1x(1);
        y = S1y(2);
    elseif p < 0.08
        %disp('Scheme 2')
        S2x = AII*T + BII;
        S2y = AII*T + BII;
        x = S2x(1);
        y = S2y(2);
    elseif p < 0.15
        %disp('Scheme 3')
        S3x = AIII*T + BII;
        S3y = AIII*T + BII;
        x = S3x(1);
        y = S3y(2);
    else
        %disp('Scheme 4')
        S4x = AIV*T + BIV;
        S4y = AIV*T + BIV;
        x = S4x(1);
        y = S4y(2);
    end
    H(n,1) = x;
    H(n,2) = y;
end
end

X = H(:,1);
Y = H(:,2);
plot(X,Y,'.')
```

I have no idea why it isn't working. Is not the iterative process correct? I run the code and I obtain the following graphic:

[image: Not a Barnsley Fern]

I figure, it might have something to do with the way I've got my if loop structured, since everything runs fine. Or perhaps, the way my schemes are defined, however they seem to be typical.

Edit: Added cleaned up code

```
function fern3()

AI = [0  0 ; 0 0.16];
AII = [ 0.85  0.04 ; -0.04 -0.85 ] ;
AIII = [ 0.2  -0.26 ; 0.23 0.22 ] ;
AIV = [-0.15  0.28 ; 0.26 0.24 ];

BI = [ 0 ; 0];
BII = [ 0 ; 1.6];
BIII = [ 0 ; 1.6];
BIV = [0 ; 0.44];

N = 10000;
I = 50;

H = zeros(N,2);

for n=1 : N

    x = rand;
    y = rand;
    T = [x;y];

    for i=1 : I
        p = rand;

        if p < 0.01
            %disp('Scheme 1')
            H(n,:) = AI*T + BI;
        elseif p < 0.08
            %disp('Scheme 2')
            H(n,:) = AII*T + BII;
        elseif p < 0.15
            %disp('Scheme 3')
            H(n,:) = AIII*T + BIII;
        else
            %disp('Scheme 4')
            H(n,:) = AIV*T + BIV;
        end
    end
end

X = H(:,1);
Y = H(:,2);
plot(X,Y,'.')
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not certain where your algorithm came from. The one on Wikipedia works well.

```
function fern
% Barnsley Fern Fractal generator
%   Using definition and pseudocode from Wikipedia
%   (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnsley_fern)

maxI = 1E7;
x = zeros(maxI,1);
y = zeros(maxI,1);

for i = 2:maxI
    r = rand;

    if (0 <= r) && (r < 0.01)
        x(i) = 0;
        y(i) = 0.16*y(i-1);
    elseif (0.01 <= r) && (r < 0.86)
        x(i) = 0.85 * x(i-1) + 0.04 * y(i-1);
        y(i) = -0.04 * x(i-1) + 0.85 * y(i-1) + 1.6;
    elseif (0.86 <= r) && (r < 0.93)
        x(i) = 0.2  * x(i-1) - 0.26 * y(i-1);
        y(i) = 0.23 * x(i-1) + 0.22 * y(i-1) + 1.6;
    else
        x(i) = -0.15 * x(i-1) + 0.28 * y(i-1);
        y(i) =  0.26 * x(i-1) + 0.24 * y(i-1) + 0.44;
    end
end

plot(x,y,'.', 'Color', [79, 121, 66]/256, 'markersize', 0.1)

end
```

[image: Fern Output]

Comment: Ah yes, however the algorithm I posted was my attempt at trying to generate it - I suppose from scratch so to say. I was wondering about the flaws in my code that are preventing the fractal from forming.

Comment: There are two problems with your algorithm. 1) You're allowing the fractal to start at any location within the domain (0,1), (0,1). This means you won't have any of the features 2) You keep on resetting the fractal after every 50 iterations, since fractals go on forever, they can't be continually reset. Also as a general comment, there are a lot of unnecessary stores that slow the code down

Comment: I've had to learn matlab in a bit of a rush, would you be able to elaborate on these "unnecessary stores".

Comment: A perfect example is in your loop. You have ` S2x = AIIT + BII; S2y = AIIT + BII; x = S2x(1); y = S2y(2);` However, S2x and S2y are the same. Then, you only use `x` and `y` by putting them back into a matrix. I put cleaned up code at the end your post